# How to return a sub-array based on an array of row indices in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do you return a sub-array based on arrays of row indices in Google Sheet?

Example sheet looks like:

```
A, 1
B, 2
C, 30
D, 4
E, 50
```

Example inputs:

```
3
5
```

which is an array `{3;5}` representing the row indices of the rows I'd like to make a sub-array of the example sheet.

Desired output:

```
C, 30
E, 50
```

which is the array `{C,30;E,50}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use Chooserows:

```
=chooserows(A1:B,tocol(D1:D,1))
```

[image]